# Using a Table Cell's Text to Access Corresponding Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Currently, I have a savedWorkout class that is simply a Table View populated with different exercises in each cell. My goal now is for the user to be able to click on each individual exercise, which will take you to a new view filled with detailed information about it.

For this, I have created an Exercise class that will hold the detailed information about the new object. Is this possible?

Here is some pseudo-code I have written up:

```
if (Table View Cell's Text == ExerciseObject.exerciseName) {
Populate a view with the corresponding information;
}
```

Being new to iPhone programming, I'm not exactly sure what would be the best way to do this, and this is what i'm thinking would be the best way to go about it.

My Exercise class holds an NSString to keep track of the exercise name, and three NSMutableArray's to hold different information.

Please let me know if I am going in the right direction.

EDIT:

After trying to implement my pseudo-code this is what I came up with:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Exercise *exerciseView = [[Exercise alloc] initWithNibName:@"Exercise" bundle:nil]; //Makes new exercise object.

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text; // Retrieves the string of the selected cell.

    exerciseView.exerciseName.text = str;

    [self presentModalViewController:exerciseView animated:YES];
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. When the new view is presented, the label doesn't show up (I connected the UILabel exerciseName to my desired string). Am I implementing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it's possible. Just use the delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

and check your data source cell based on the index location.

Comment: Cool. Does my method sound correct? Just implement it within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: yes, looks right to me. let me know if you run into issues, you could share your code and i'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks, I ran into a bit of an issue, so if you could look over my code that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  If done traditionally, it uses the indexPath.row to access an array of exercises to get a particular exercise, then changes cell properties based on the particular exercise.  Is that about right?

It so, then you're halfway home.

**EDIT**
1) Use the code *inside* your cellForRowAtIndex path to init your str, as indicated here.
2) The new view controller view hasn't been built yet.  You can't initialize a subview in the view hierarchy before the VC is ready.  You need to pass the string to a property in that view controller (in a custom init method if you want), then on that class's viewDidLoad, you can set the exerciseName field to the string property you saved earlier.  That subview shouldn't be part of the classes public interface.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // There should be an array of exercises, the same one used in cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    NSString *str = [self.myArrayOfExercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Just made code up here, but however you get a string to place in the cell
    // in cellForRowAtIndexPath do that same thing here.

    Exercise *exerciseView = [[Exercise alloc] initWithNibName:@"Exercise" bundle:nil];
    // Might be wise to rename this ExerciseViewController, since it's probably (hopefully) a ViewController subclass

    // no need to get a table cell, you have the info you need from your exercise array
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text; // Retrieves the string of the selected cell.

    exerciseView.exerciseName.text = str;

    [self presentModalViewController:exerciseView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Returns null when I print exerciseView.exerciseName.text to an NSLog statement.

Comment: Do this - NSLog(@"view=%@ exerciseName=%@ exerciseName.text=%@, str=%@", exerciseView, exerciseView.exerciseName, exerciseView.exerciseName.text, str);  It's probably nil starting at exerciseName.  Paste the log output here.

Comment: Output: view=<Exercise: 0x395d7d0> exerciseName=(null) exerciseName.text=(null), str=Vertical Leg Crunch

Comment: Yes.  I will answer here and in your other question.  I was so distracted by your strange use of the cellForRowAtIndex in the selection, that I missed the other mistake in the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I should make a new property in this class? Or in my Exercise class? I'm still a little confused.

Comment: I'm not sure in which question to converse.  I added a code illustration in the other one.  Sorry about that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10375/discussion-between-danh-and-topchef)